# Purge command in Discord.NET doesn't work

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to make a bot using Discord.NET in C#, I was working on the purge command but every help online is all outdated from the older syntaxes, there's no more DeleteMessagesAsync from what I know, does anyone know a way I can fix this?

```cs
        [Command("purge")]
        [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
        [RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
        public async Task PurgeAsync(int delnum)
        {
            //Important Contexts:
            //Context.User;
            //Context.Client;
            //Context.Guild;
            //Context.Message
            //Context.Channel;
            var items = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(delnum + 1).FlattenAsync();
            await Context.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(items);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they just moved it, I casted it over and worked.